# List files on ftp using cURL in Matlab

Tags: list, matlab, curl, ftp

I'm trying to get a directory listing of files on an ftp server using cURL commands within Matlab.  Currently I'm trying something like:

```
[s,w] = dos('curl "ftp://name:password@ftpurl/directory/"');
```

which correctly gets the data and stores it in the variable w.

To get a list of the files in that directory I could try to parse out the names from the 'w' variable, but that could get a little complicated.  Is there an easier way to obtain a list of the file names within the ftp directory, or do I have to go about trying to grab it out of the w variable?

Thanks!

**EDIT**

Using the -l command:

```
[s,w] = dos('curl "ftp://name:password@ftpurl/directory/"');
```

The resulting w looks something like:

> 0 0 0 763 0 0 2319 0 --:--:-- 2437FTPtest-D20110322-T022705.bot
>
> FTPtest-D20110322-T022705.idx
>
> FTPtest-D20110322-T022705.raw
>
> FTPtest-D20110322-T022746.bot

So it looks much better, but since the first file doesn't have a line feed before, it may be a little more difficult.  Any ideas on how to get around this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the -l (that's a lowercase L) option:

> When listing an FTP directory, this switch forces a name-
>                 only  view. Especially useful if you want to machine-parse the
>                 contents of an FTP directory since  the  normal directory  view
>                 doesn't use a standard look or format.
>
> This  option  causes  an  FTP NLST command to be sent. Some FTP
>                 servers list only files in their response to NLST; they do not
>                 include subdirectories and symbolic links.

(quote originates from http://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html#-l)

Comment: Awesome, that definitely looks like it will help.  I'm not sure if it's Matlab or cURL, though, but it doesn't put a line break before the first file, which means it's scrunched together with the data transfer info.  I'm sure I can work around it, but do you have any idea why that's happening?  Thanks for the help!

Comment: before the first file name there won't be any "line break", the newlines should be after each file name.

Comment: Yeah, I've started parsing it out using the line breaks and carriage returns.  Looks like it should work out ok.  Thanks again for the help.

Answer (score 0):

How about use Matlab's built-in ftp support instead of shelling out to curl? See "help ftp".

Comment: Matlab's ftp function isn't very robust, and I've seen people recommend using cURL instead.  I've tried the dir function on an ftp object, but it won't work.  I don't know if it's because Matlab doesn't support passive ftp or if it's a security issue.  I don't know enough about ftp, but as for now cURL is working but Matlab's 'ftp' function is not.